# Android app indexing not working when searched from chrome app

Tags: android, search, indexing, android-manifest, intentfilter

I have integrated app indexing for my android app so that whenever user search from mobile google, list of site will be listed out,on clicking my site it will take to my android app instead of webpage. This works fine when i search from google search app, whereas the same is not working when i search my chrome browser app.

Have implemented using this guide http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2014/06/android-app-indexing-is-now-open-for.html

This was the intent filter i have used in my manifest

```
<intent-filter >
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                 <data android:scheme="http"
                       android:host="mysitedomain"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I have also tried with `<category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER" />`
 I have done site verify from developer console.

Do i am missing any configuration settings
Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain how it works. I am getting confused by google document. When the link opens our app.I worked with my project. What are the things need to take care. Could you please explain step by step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever we need an app to be called by clicking link from chrome browser, definitely that app should include pathPrefix in data tag of intent filter

in my case for app indexing search from chrome browser i need to include this.

```
<intent-filter >
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                 <data android:scheme="http"
                       android:host="mysitedomain"
                       android:pathPrefix="/" />
</intent-filter>
```